# Connect to capture driver without creating window

Tags: c#, winapi, video, video-capture

How can I connect to video capture driver without creating a capture window. Is this possible ? In the other word, I want to capture video from user webcam without showing preview window.

Comment: @MicahArmantrout When if you don't have any idea about the topic please don't offer any advice. People are familiar with this know what I've tried to do. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a window only with legacy [Video for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757708%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API. With [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [Media Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), window is not necessary for video capture. In C# you can interface to those APIs using open source [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) and [Media Foundation.NET](http://mfnet.sourceforge.net/) libraries.

FYI: DirectShow.NET includes CapWMV sample in C# that captures video into file.

> A .NET sample application using the WM ASF Writer filter to create an
>   wmv file    While the underlying libraries are covered by LGPL, this
>   sample is released  as public domain.  It is distributed in the hope
>   that it will be useful, but  WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the
>   implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY  or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
>   PURPOSE.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your reply Roman, but I think DirectShow is more complicated than VfW, am I right? It seems there is no way, I've to switch to DirectShow or Media Foundation.

Comment: Well, the APIs might be somewhat difficult, but they are not onyl about video capture - they are multimedia APIs. `Video for Windows` is really deprecated, I would rather you not use it. I would say the richest API is DirectShow - more compatible hardware, more sample code, compatibility across versions of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Using VfW, you need to (at least) create the video/capture window, but you can give it a null window handle as the parent and make it not visible. All communication from the VfW library is done via StdCall callbacks.
I'm not 100% but I don't think you need to run a message pump either.

As [Roman says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11235268/588306) you should look at DirectShow as it obsoleted VfW about 15 years ago now.